# Django: Use a QuerySet in Function

Tags: django

I want to make some tournament matches in a DetailView. But I can't figure out how to make a query of all registrations **context['regs']** and use the queryset in my function **create_matches()**.

```
class KategorieDetail(DetailView):
    model = Kategorie
    context_object_name = 'kategorie'

    def create_matches(regs):
        red_corner = []
        blue_corner = []
        matches = []

        # Separate the regs into both corners
        i = 1
        for reg in regs:
            if i%2 == 1:
                red_corner.append(reg)
            else:
                blue_corner.append(reg)
            i += 1

        # Create Match-Ups
        while blue_corner:
            match = {'red': red_corner.pop(), 'blue': blue_corner.pop()}
            matches.append(match)

        return matches


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(KategorieDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        kid = context['kategorie'].id
        context['regs'] = Registrierung.objects.filter(kategorie=context['kategorie'].id)
        context['regs_count'] = context['regs'].count()
        context['matches'] = create_matches(context['regs'].values(), kid)

        return context
```

In my HTML-View I can't display the matches. If I say `{{matches}}`, I get:

> HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/events/"

I also don't get why I have to give the Kategorie_ID to the create_matches(regs) function.

Comment: Declaring a method in the class and not using self.

Comment: This can't be your real code; it would give a NameError, because `create_matches` is an instance method, not a global function.

Comment: Unless you *also* have a view function called `create_matches`. That would make sense, especially if it's returning a redirect.

Comment: Why is `create_matches` defined in the class body? Either put it outside as a top level function, or change it into a method (with a `self` argument, and call with `self.create_matches(regs)` )

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Used: **context['matches'] = self.create_matches(context['regs'])** and added "self" to parameter list **def create_matches(self, regs):**